# How does Hugo maintain site-wide data, like .Site.AllPages?

Tags: go, hugo

I'm looking for some bite-sized examples on how Hugo *might* be managing site-wide data, like `Site.AllPages`.

Specifically, Hugo seems *too fast* to be reading in *every* file and it's metadata, before beginning to generate pages and making things like `.Site.AllPages` available -- but obviously that has to be the case.

Are Ruby (Jekyll) and Python (Pelican) really just that slow, **or is there some specific (algorithmic) method that Hugo employs to generate pages before everything is ready?**

Comment: Maybe read [the source](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/master/hugolib/site.go#L61)?

Comment: Ruby and Python are *much* slower than their proponents would like you to believe.

Comment: @captncraig *Maybe* I'm still new to Go, and wouldn't have known exactly where to look, after having spent no less than 30 minutes digging around the Hugo project files already. Given you are probably a nice, helpful person, the phrasing and short length of your comment doesn't come across that way. Please be gentle with potential noobs in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no magic, and Hugo does not start any rendering until the `.Site.Pages` etc. collections are filled and ready.

Some key points here:

- We have a processing pipeline where we do concurrent processing whenever we can, so your CPUs should be pretty busy.
- Whenever we do content manipulation (shortcodes, emojis etc.), you will most likely see a hand crafted parser or replacement function that is built for speed.
- We really care about the "being fast" part, so we have a solid set of benchmarks to reveal any performance regressions.
- Hugo is built with `Go` -- which is really fast, and have a really great set of tools for this (`pprof`, benchmark support etc.)

Some other points that makes the `hugo server` variant even faster than the regular `hugo` build:

- Hugo uses a virtual file system, and we render directly to memory when in server/development mode.
- We have some partial reloading logic in there. So, even if we render everything every time, we try to reload and rebuild only the content files that have changed and we don't reload/rebuild templates if it is a content change etc.

I'm bep on GitHub, the main developer on Hugo.

Comment: Great answer. +1. I was trying to get back to the origin of Site.page with my answer, but yours is more specific.

Comment: @bep Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I'm still relatively new to Go, and was intensely curious about the internals of Hugo. So, is it not an oversimplification that all content/meta is read into some kind of structure and (held in memory?) and then concurrent tasks start building pages?

Comment: Most of the data is in memory when the rendering starts (we do a fair amount of lazy loading/lazy generating of stuff accessed from templates -- i.e. we don't need to calculate reading time of every content file if that value is never used in the templates), but simplified, you could look at it as:

file reading and processing (concurrent) -- site assembly etc. (serial, i.e. one Go routine) -- rendering (concurrent)

Answer (score 1):

You can see [`AllPages` in `hugolib/page_collections.go`](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/blob/873a6f18851bcda79d562ff6c02e1109e8e31a88/hugolib/page_collections.go#L28-L30).

A `git blame` shows that it was modified in [Sept. 2016 for Hugo v0.18 in commit 698b994](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/commit/698b994f714174449fd1ea37c39058ea14f6deee), in order to fix [PR 2297 Fix Node vs Page](https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/2297).

That PR references the [discussion/improvement proposal "Node improvements"](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/node-improvements/1593)

> Most of the "problems" with this gets much easier once we agree that a page is just a page that is just a ... page...
>
> And that a Node is just a Page with a discriminator.
>
> So:
>
> - Today's pages are Page with discriminator "page"
> - Homepage is Page with discriminator "home" or whatever
> - Taxonomies are Pages with discriminator "taxonomy"
> - ...
>
> They have some structural differences (pagination etc.), but they are basically just pages.
>
> With that in mind we can put them all in one collection and add query filters on discriminator:
>
> - `.Site.Pages`: filtered by discriminator = 'page'
>     `*.Site.All`: No filter
> - `where`: when the sequence is Pages add discriminator = 'page', but let user override

That key (the discriminator) allows to retrieve quickly all 'pages'.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer with details, and clarity, pointing out where things are, etc. Very helpful way to answer.